# ¿Qué procedimiento usar para saber el tamaño total asignado a una BD en SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi consulta es si se puede estimar el tamaño máximo asignado a una base de datos, entiendo que no implica que sea este el tamaño de la BD, que vendría ser el tamaño usado u ocupado en disco, y para este caso hay varios procedimientos del sistema que me han permitido averiguarlo, aunque tengo dudas si es el total asignado, o solo el usado en el resultado del procedimiento `sp_databases`.

El otro procedimiento es `sp_spaceused`, este me da más luces para poder hallar el espacio total asignado aunque no entiendo muy bien el segundo resultado del procedimiento en la siguiente consulta:

```
USE Northwind
GO
EXEC sp_spaceused  
GO
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo el segundo resultado con los campos reserved, data, index_size, unused.

¿Puedo hallar el tamaño total asignado con este procedimiento?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tamaño de la base de datos viene dado en el campo `database_size`.

Aquí tienes el significado de cada uno de los campos:

- **reservado** (*varchar(18)*) → Espacio total asignado por los objetos de la base de datos.
- **datos** (*varchar(18)*) → Cantidad total de espacio utilizado por los datos.
- **index_size** (*varchar(18)*) → Cantidad total de espacio utilizado por índices.
- **no utilizado** (*varchar(18)*) → Espacio total reservado para los objetos de la base de datos, pero no utilizado todavía.

**[Fuente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188776.aspx)**

Comment: En conclusión, que campos sumo para estimar el tamaño total de una base de datos (entiéndase por el tamaño sin usar más el usado). ¿Está bien si sumo database_size + unallocated_space+ reserved? Por favor ayúdame con ese dilema. gracias

Comment: El tamaño de la base de datos que vas a poder utilizar, viene dado por `database_size`. El campo `unallocated space` es un espacio que no se ha reservado para objetos de base de datos. Si aun sigo sin responder tu pregunta, es que no te llego a entender.

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿el campo `database_size` es el espacio que ocupa la base de datos en disco? es decir que el `unallocated` está incluido dentro de ese espacio?, y en su defecto el `reserved`, que por cierto resultó ser la suma de `data`, `index_size`, y `unused`... ¿Es así?

Comment: @Fran.J Es así ;)